# Pi: one common network between Wi-Fi module and Ethernet

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, linux, pi-b+

I have Raspberry Pi B+, and a compatible (I have checked, it worked), Wi-Fi module for the Pi. I am also using Raspbian.

My task is build a router using the Pi, (with a Wi-Fi access point).

But, one important detail there.
I *don't need* internet access on this setup. This setup will only give us communication between Wi-Fi (1 or more) and Ethernet (1) clients.

For example, in this LAN:

- 192.168.1.1 - is the Pi itself
- 192.168.1.10 - Ethernet client
- 192.168.1.15 - Wi-Fi client #1
- 192.168.1.20 - Wi-Fi client #2
- ...

How do I build a router using Pi, which works without internet by the method described above?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a bridge between `wlan0` and `eth0` networks.

Here are the commands you need to run:

```
brctl addbr br0 #Create bridge interface

brctl addif br0 eth0 wlan0 #Add interfaces to the bridge
```

Now you can proceed with DHCP/other things. Interface what you will need to use there - br0, not the `wlan0`/`eth0` ones.

For Raspbian the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
iface eth0 inet manual

iface wlan0 inet manual

iface br0 inet static

bridge_ports eth0 eth1

#address/netmask/whatever ...
```